# Windows 10 - Must Exit Greenshot in order for Ctrl-C to automatically copy to clipboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, clipboard, greenshot

This isn't an issue in Windows 7 Pro (home PC) or Windows 8 (work) but in **Windows 10** (laptop) **I have to manually EXIT Greenshot whenever I want to copy/paste TEXT using the Ctrl + C keyboard shortcut.** Because I'm copying/pasting text, not a screenshot, it should automatically copy to the clipboard when using the keyboard shortcut. Note, the mouse rt-click copy function works fine but I don't always use a mouse on my laptop.

**If I DON'T exit Greenshot first, when I click Ctrl + C I get the Greenshot destination menu box popping up, which then requires me to select "Copy to clipboard".** An unnecessary extra step and really irritating because I've already tried pasting it several times (out of decades of habit) before I remember I hadn't clicked the destination and it's not in my clipboard yet.

How can I adjust settings so it works in Windows 10 just like it does in Windows 7 and 8?

I ran the "Run compatibility troubleshooter" and it did not fix. I tried selecting Windows 10 from the Compatibility mode drop-down box beneath the troubleshooter, but Windows 10 is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, it sounds as if someone has configured Greenshot on your Windows 10 notebook to take a screenshot when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. I suggest checking the settings by right-clicking the Greenshot systray icon, then clicking *Settings*. The keyboard shortcuts are configured right in the *General* tab. If one of the text fields says "Ctrl + C",  change it to something else and your problem should be fixed.

[image: Greenshot settings]

Comment: Also worth mentioning that "Druck" means "Print", or "PrtSc" ;)